# Calling PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials with incorrect credentials locks account

Tags: c#, active-directory, ntlm

I found the following code to validate NT domain users, but if incorrect password entered too many times, the account will get locked out.

Is there an API call that will not lockout users if incorrect passwords are entered? Of course, assuming no change to current lockout policy.

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
{
    return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to authenticate against the domain credentials without adhering to whatever authentication policies are in place.

Comment: This will be completely dependent on your ActiveDirectory rules.  Thats the reason they are there.  If you want around this for testing, talk to IT and get a user created that doesnt have this restriction.